# How to write in bash to ssh to different machine and create tmux session then run some command in it

Tags: ssh, scripting, tmux

Basically I want to write some script like

```
#!/bin/bash
for idx in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
        echo machine$idx
        ssh machine$idx tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession$idx" python run.py
done
```

which can do the thing separately as:

```
ssh machine$idx 

tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession$idx"

python run.py
```

but after many trial and error, I still cannot make it work as expected.

**UPDATE** following Tagwint's advice, my script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for idx in 1 2 3 4 5 6
do
        ssh machine$idx <<REMSH
        tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession"
        tmux send-keys -t -s "myTempSession" python Space run.py  C-m
        REMSH
done
```

but it prompts:

```
./dist_run.sh: line 8: warning: here-document at line 4 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `REMSH')
./dist_run.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

**UPDATE** I modify it to be

```
#!/bin/bash
for idx in 36 37
do
        ssh machine$idx <<REMSH
        tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession"
        tmux send-keys -t -s "myTempSession" python Space run.py C-m
REMSH
done
```

this works, but after run the script, I log into `machine36` and `machine37`, go into the opened myTempSession, the `python run.py` is not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you HERE-DOC apporach

```
ssh machine$idx <<REMSH
tmux new-session -d -s "myTempSession$idx"
tmux send-keys -t "myTempSession$idx" python Space run.py  C-m 
REMSH
```

Note $idx part in session name will most probably resolve in nothing
unless you have a idx environment variable defined
so you'll get session name just myTempSession

Comment: thank you, @Tagwint pls see my update, there is maybe some typos

Comment: HERE-DOC is picky about indentations, so you did it right.
I dont know how `python run.py`  should look like to prove it is executed
Any errors shown?
Either python or run.py may just not be visible. 
My first guess is - Try adding /full/path/to/python and 
/full/path/toyour/run,py

Comment: I guess in the `send-keys -t -s "myTempSession"` line you should remove -s. 
Make it look `send-keys -t "myTempSession" ......`
that's copy/paste typo ), I'll update my answer above

Comment: I finally make it work as : `tmux new-session -d -s "launch_train" \; send-keys "python run.py`